# Deploy MVC 4 application 4.5 Framework 1and1 hosting

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-4, web-deployment, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to deploy an mvc 4 project in vs2012 via FTP on 1and1.com

This is what I'm getting.

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
>   The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

Are there settings on 1and1 I need to set somewhere because it's an MVC proj or changes in webconfig?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because company-specific hosting questions will go out of date quickly, and will need to be maintained or deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1and1 windows package doesn't support MVC.  You would need to update to their server package. ~59/month

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer, but I didn't enjoy reading it. Pretty annoyed that a windows host couldn't run MVC. Going to bite the bullet and ship the basic site I've got back over to WebForms.

Comment: I know this is an old post.  I just want to let you know that they offer support both MVC 3 and 4 right now.

Comment: @Auguste Hi, can you please refer a tutorial to deploy .net application to 1and1 amazingly  they don't have cPanel or plesk so i don't understand from where should I start. thanks,

Answer (score 3):

@dright, Are you still encountering the problem?  It appears 1and1.com has updated their hosting package to support 4/4.5 Framework with their Basic Windows hosting plans (https://www.1and1.com/windows-hosting?linkId=hd.subnav.windowshosting).  I purchased a plan as a sandbox for deploying little apps that I develop.

I have successfully deployed a Asp.Net application using the  WebMatrix IDE. But I have struggled using VS2013 template/default applications' Web.Config.  I was curious if you have had any luck.

Thanks!

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I just wanted to state that while they do support mvc it is on medium trust so a lot of stuff is off the cards, like Ninject and  Moq and other 3rd party stuff